# React Native TouchableOpacity OnPress not Working with loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a scrollview in which multiple items are generated with loop. I added TouchableOpacity above these items because i want these objects to be touchable. But when i add a method on onPress method it shows error **not a function , is undefined**

**List_Data Component:**

```
class List_Data extends React.Component {

    fetchData = () => {
        console.log("DONE");
    }

    _renderView = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, padding: 20}}>
                        <View style={styles.container}>
                            <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} >
                                {
                                    this.state.Data.map(function (data, index) {
                                        return (
                                            <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this.fetchData()}>
                                                <Image source={{uri: data.imageSrc}}
                                                       resizeMode={'cover'}
                                                       style={{width: '100%', height: imageHeight}}
                                                />
                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                        );
                                    })
                                }
                            </ScrollView>
                        </View>
                    </View>
        )
    }


    render() {
        return (
            {this._renderView()}
        );
    }
}
```

I don't know whats the issue, it just a method which prints on console.

Comment: Change `this.state.Data.map(function (data, index) {` to `this.state.Data.map((data, index) => {`. Your problem here is that the context of `this` isn't quite what you are expecting. When you use arrow functions, the context of `this` is lexically scoped.

Comment: still same issue...

Comment: did you tried `this.fetchData.bind(this)` ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is coming from your `.map`. Basically you are losing the value of `this` as you are not using an arrow function. If you change your `.map(function(data, index)` to `.map((data,index) =>` it should work.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    Data: [
      {imageSrc :'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/39.jpg'},
      {imageSrc: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/38.jpg'},
      {imageSrc: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/37.jpg'},
      {imageSrc: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/36.jpg'},
      {imageSrc: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/35.jpg'},
      {imageSrc: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/34.jpg'},
    ]
  }

  // let's pass something so that we know that it is working
  fetchData = (index) => {
    alert(`you pressed ${index}`)
  }

  _renderView = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} >
            {
              this.state.Data.map((data, index) =>  { // change this to an arrow function
                  return (
                      <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this.fetchData(index)}> 
                          <Image source={{uri: data.imageSrc}} 
                                  resizeMode={'cover'}
                                  style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
                          />
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                  );
              })
            }
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this._renderView()
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

You can see it working in the following snack https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/map-with-arrow-function

Answer (score 0):

Try keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true} under ScrollView. `<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}>`